# Change the user_login at registration

Tags: users, login

I use a third party plugin that adds Social Login option to my blog. It works very well, but I dislike that **when users choose to login by their social accounts** the user login names (`user_login` in database) are saved in this format - "*First-Second*", so the first letter of the each part are capitals. My own `user_login` will be "Iurie-Malai", but I would like "iurie-malai".

I know that WordPress usernames are case-insensitive, but I want that user logins to be only in lowercase. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hook into the [`user_register`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register) action hook and lower case the strings manually, by using the [`wp_update_user`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_user) function. Here's a quick example:

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'callback_function', 10, 1 );

function callback_function( $user_id ) {
    // Get the user by their ID
    $user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );
    // Update their user_login
    wp_update_user(
        array( 
            'ID'         => $user_id, 
            'user_login' => strtolower( $user->user_login ) 
        )
    );
}
```

### Using the [`pre_user_login`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_user_login-3/) filter

You can use the above filter to filter the user's login before its added to the database, as follows:

```
add_filter( 'pre_user_login', 'callback_function' );
function callback_function( $login ) {
    return strtolower( $login );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I am not sure if my initial question was very clear, so I updated it. Your answer is about user meta, not about `user_login`, as I asked.

Comment: You're welcome. I've updated the answer.